# crear un login personalizado laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy tratando de crear un login personalizado, mi login seria asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pontano+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-feJI7QwhOS+hwpX2zkaeJQjeiwlhOP+SdQDqhgvvo1DsjtiSQByFdThsxO669S2D" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .wrap {
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }

        body{
           overflow-x: hidden;
           background: #0c546024;
           font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        #conte{
            position: absolute;
            width:28%;
            padding: 5rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 7px 7px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            background: #0c5460;
            top: 21%;
            left: 34%;
        }

        #input-form{
            width:100%;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 8px;
            border: 0px;
            padding: 0.8rem;
            font-size: 0.7rem;
        }

        #img{
            height: 80px;
            margin: 1rem;
        }

        #forgot{
            text-align: center;

        }
            #text-forgot{
                color:white; 
                text-decoration: underline;
                font-size: 0.7rem;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" class="wrap">
    <div class="container" id="conte" >
        <!-- Formulario -->
        <form action="/loginme" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="USUARIO" id="input-form">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="PASSWORD" id="input-form" style="color:gray; background: #dee2e6; margin-top: -7px;">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <!-- Imagen -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" style="text-align: center;">
                    <img src="../img/logo.png" id="img">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Recuperar Contraseña -->
        <div class="container" id="forgot">
            <a href="" id="text-forgot">RECUPERA TU CONTRASEÑA</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

se que editando el archivo .env configuro la base de datos y mi usuario y password , ejecutando el comando php artisan make:auth creo como unas vistas predeterminadas y luego php artisan migrate pero no se que mas cambiar en el monton de archivos. Quisiera un login que use un usuario de mi db ubicado en una tabla llamada user, la vista de mi login quisiera que fuera la que yo cree y con un metodo de recuperacion de contraseña en teoria se ve sencillo pero no he usado laravel

Comment: En principio su pregunta es muy amplia para realizar un login "personalizado" hay que cambiar detalles de los archivos que le crea el comando `make:auth` dependiendo de que nivel de "personalización" desee , recomendaría leer la [documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/) o blogs sobre esto.

Comment: agregue un poco mas de detalles, no se que mas podria colocar, gracias

Comment: Todo lo que quiere hace ya se lo proporciona Laravel por defecto al hacer  `make:auth`, solo tendría que cambiar lo de la vista `login` , en `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`  ,está su vista `login`